# Running integration tests with Cucumber/capybara/celerity on a Jruby on Rails application using mysql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, cucumber, jruby, celerity

I've got an application I've been working on with ruby 1.9.1. I'd like to test the javascript in my UI and the default selenium driver for capybara doesn't support the events I need to test.

So I'm going through the process of using rvm to switch the application on to jruby for testing, since apparently celertiy/culerity only work on jruby at the moment. I've got my bundle installed and the application seems to work correctly on jruby, but when I try to run 'rake cucumber' I get the following output:

> 

```
Using the default profile...
superclass mismatch for class SQLiteAdapter (TypeError)
/home/david/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.3@test2/gems/database_cleaner-0.5.2/lib/database_cleaner/active_record/truncation.rb:11
/home/david/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.3@test2/gems/database_cleaner-0.5.2/lib/database_cleaner/active_record/truncation.rb:239:in `require'
/home/david/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.3@test2/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/home/david/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.3@test2/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
/home/david/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.3@test2/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/home/david/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.3@test2/gems/database_cleaner-0.5.2/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:86:in `orm_strategy'
/home/david/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.3@test2/gems/database_cleaner-0.5.2/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:42:in `create_strategy'
/home/david/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.3@test2/gems/database_cleaner-0.5.2/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:56:in `strategy='
/home/david/rental/features/support/env.rb:58
/home/david/rental/features/support/env.rb:143:in `load'
/home/david/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.3@test2/gems/cucumber-0.9.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:143:in `load_code_file'
/home/david/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.3@test2/gems/cucumber-0.9.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:158:in `load_file'
/home/david/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.3@test2/gems/cucumber-0.9.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:61:in `load_files!'
/home/david/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.3@test2/gems/cucumber-0.9.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:60:in `each'
/home/david/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.3@test2/gems/cucumber-0.9.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:60:in `load_files!'
/home/david/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.3@test2/gems/cucumber-0.9.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:185:in `load_step_definitions'
/home/david/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.3@test2/gems/cucumber-0.9.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:26:in `run!'
/home/david/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.3@test2/gems/cucumber-0.9.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:54:in `execute!'
/home/david/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.3@test2/gems/cucumber-0.9.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:29:in `execute'
/home/david/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.3@test2/gems/cucumber-0.9.2/bin/cucumber:8
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [bundle exec /home/david/.rvm/rubies/jruby-...]
```

At one point I was using sqlite for my test db, but have since changed.  I've even tried changing back to sqlite, but still get the same error.  If I disable database_cleaner in features/support/env.rb the tests run, but they all fail mysteriously.

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Rails 3.0.0 is not compatible with Ruby 1.9.1. Use Ruby 1.9.2 instead

Comment: Is it just 1.9.1 that has the problem or all versions < 1.9.2? Since jruby is based off 1.8.7 that could explain the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this is a problem with the way that database cleaner and jdbc are interacting.

http://github.com/tmikoss/database_cleaner/commit/83d85cf7740e4aef97dd6fd5c0908cb09a2f0ca9

UPDATE:
I found this question because I was struggling with the same issue. The version of database_cleaner I linked to above does indeed fix the issue, there is an issue on the database_cleaner project that notifies the team of the issue as well. I was able to get around it for the moment by:

```
# someplace on your computer    
git clone http://github.com/tmikoss/database_cleaner.git

#in your projects Gemfile
gem "database_cleaner", :path => "path/to/above/copy/of/gem"
```

UPDATE UPDATE:
this fix should be available on v0.6.0 of database_cleaner master

Comment: This worked. All I had to do was specify 0.6.0 in my Gemfile and it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that the SQLite adapter you're using is compatible with jRuby? You'd need the following:

Gems: `activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter` and `jdbc-sqlite3`

(I always install both, you might be good to go with only `activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter`)

Then edit `config/database.yml` to use the jdbcsqlite3 adapter:

```
cucumber:
  adapter: jdbcsqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  timeout: 5000
```

Comment: I'm currently using mysql, not sqlite3.  I did try switching to sqlite3 to see if that would solve the issue (it did not) and I did use the jdbc adapters. Thanks for the input!